# how to display a tooltip while hovering on chart js line

Tags: javascript, charts, hover, tooltip, line

Normaly tooltips are display for points but in this case i want to display a tooltip when you hover on the line which is the intersection between tow point

[display tooltip when hover on the circled area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWBzj.png)